# Wildfly remoting: how to limit number of login attempts?

Tags: authentication, ejb, wildfly, limit

I am using Wildfly 16 for an application that is accessed by remote EJB clients. The EJBs are secured, and I am using the database login module that is part of Wildfly.

I'd like to implement something like a "fail2ban" for the application, e.g. disallowing connects for 5mins for a user if invalid credentials were provided in a sequence of 5 attempts.

- Is there any solution by means of configuration?
- If not, what could be a solution? Writing a custom login module and keeping an in-memory map of user ids and number of failed logins?

Thanks!